# Yii2 "Page not found" when using CRUD generator

Tags: crud, yii2, scaffolding

I have succesfully used Yii2 Model & CRUD Generators to obtain some skeleton code files for my web app. Particularly, the CRUD Generator claims to have succesfully created its view files into:

```
<yii_root>/basic/views/<my_view_name>/*.php
```

which I got by leaving "View Path" field blank.

However, browsing to:

```
https://<my_site_FQDN>/basic/web/index.php?r=<my_view_name>/index
```

spits a "Not Found (#404)" error and I'm unable to find any useful info in the Yii2 debug logs.

Any idea on this matter shall be welcome.

Antonio

Comment: can u show a screen shot of your folder structure please

Comment: ![Folder structure](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7z6q1gzfk8iqn5r/folders.png?dl=0)

Comment: In the folders, "bibliografia" is an example of this issue.

Comment: Can u please place the "BibliografiaController.php" under the controllers folder and try it??

Comment: It fails and throws:      Unknown Class – yii\base\UnknownClassException
Unable to find 'app\controllers\BibliografiaController' in file: /usr/local/share/datos/tmp/desarrollo/yii/magado/controllers/BibliografiaController.php. Namespace missing?

Comment: "magado" is just an alternative install folder name I chose instead of "basic".

Comment: which server are u using?? apache or nginx??.. Also try this as well. configure your server in such a way so that /usr/local/share/datos/tmp/desarrollo/yii/magado/web is the document_root folder & try to access it via https://<my_site_FQDN>/index.php?r=<my_controller_name>/index

Comment: Sorry, I noticed I had to change the namespace inside BibliografiaController after moving it to 'controllers' folder, from:  'namespace app\controllers\bibliografia' to 'namespace app\controllers' and now it works! However I still cannot figure out why it does not work inside the previous subfolder.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`<my_view_name>` this is a terrible way of looking at this. Read about MVC.

You are creating controllers, routes are to controllers not to views. Stop looking if the views are there... look if the controller is there. You never interact with a view, you always do with a controller. So, is your controller there? are you sure you have created it?

Also what is the controller name? if you have something like ProductCategory then the correct route is

```
https://<my_site_FQDN>/basic/web/index.php?r=product-category/index
```

and not

```
https://<my_site_FQDN>/basic/web/index.php?r=ProductCategory/index
```

**Edit**
Ok, I see your problem, stop putting folders under other folders and so on. You created your CRUD wrong. Your controller has to be directly under controllers not under controllers/bibliografia, the same goes for the model. Delete the files and start again with CRUD as probably your namespaces are also wrong.

Comment: I admit I'm a complete noob in MVC frameworks but in this case Yii2' CRUD Generator has done the whole job automagically, even creating the controller (which does exist).

Comment: what is the name of the controller? 1 word or 2 words?

Comment: BibliografiaController, that's the usual convention in Yii2: <model>Controller. Using 'bibliografia-controller' or even 'BibliografiaController' makes no difference.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot for the point. I'll redo all that jazz tomorrow: but is that a Yii2 limitation? The CRUD generator supposedly allows to specify an "arbitrary" path to controllers and models

Comment: It is not a limitation, it just would take too long to explain to you how to set it all up. Because you are still learning try to not modify how it works for now, until you figure out what is what.

Comment: the controller part is never part of the route mate, `BibliografiaController` will be a route with `/bibliografia` . A route with `BibliografiaPersonController` will be `/bibliografia-person`. The actual word Controller is never part of any route. Your problem is that you actually have extra folders in there. So when a controller is in `controllers/bibliografia/BibliografiaController` but your namespace is just `controllers` yii2 does not know that it needs to search in another folder to find what it needs.

Comment: Also, if your CRUD is intended for backend, make sure to use render as follows:

return $this->render('@backend/views/whatever/someview', [
   'model' => $model,
]);

Comment: @gvanto I do not think that is necessary, the controller in the backend would search automatically there first.

Comment: @MihaiP yeah I thought so too. Turns out it doesn't.

Answer (score 7):

In my case, Yii2 consistenly writes the following with gii CRUD auto-generator.

```
namespace app\Controllers;
```

Notice uppercase 'C' for Controllers. This causes 404 error.
It should be :

```
namespace app\controllers
```

This fixed my 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

I found with Yii2 (advanced template) that the generated controllers had:

```
namespace app\controllers;
```

I had to change this to:

```
namespace frontend\controllers;
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by capitalizing the first letter of the controller name.
Controller name should start with capital letters.
If lower case is used, Controller generator won't throw any error, but you will get not found(404) error in the browser.

this threw an error:

```
app\controllers\testController
```

this worked:

```
 app\controllers\TestController
```

Answer (score -2):

Its very Simple, change the namespace and please be careful while creating CRUD.. 
change namespace app\controllers; to namespace backend\controllers;